# Публикация статуса Твиттер  в группе (или странице) В Контакте

Tags: твиттер, php, вконтакте

> or_die, в логах ошибки пропали, но
> ничего на странице не публикуется...
> После выполнения скрипта выводится
> сообщение "Update". на файл куков и
> твитов стоят права 777, на сам скрипт
> 644, и в файл куков и в файл твитов
> после выполнения скрипта все
> записывается.

Есть скрипт, с помощью него можно публиковать статусы twitter в вконтакте автоматически, но я хотел бы публиковать не на стене профиля, а в группе или официальной странице, например: `http://vkontakte.ru/of_stranica`, как нужно изменит скрипт?
P.S. Вот сам скрипт:

```
<?php
 /* 
    tvkontakte 0.1i
    vkontakte.ru status updater from twitter
    made by Vladimir Smirnoff
    http://orl.sumy.ua
    mail@smirnoff.sumy.ua
    improved by Kichrum
    http://Kichrum.org.ua
 */

# Конфигурация - ОТРЕДАКТИРУЙ!
define ('TWITTER_USERNAME','MyLogin'); // MyLogin заменить на свой Логин в Twitter
define ('VKONTAKTE_LOGIN','user@mail.ua'); // user@mail.ua заменить на свой E-mail на Vkontakte.ru
define ('VKONTAKTE_PASSWORD','12345'); // gfhjkm  заменить на свой Пароль на Vkontakte.ru
define ('PREPEND_WORD','Twitter.com/user'); // Twitter.com/user заменить на Слово,  которое будет перед статусом: максимальная длинна: 20 символов с пробелами = 160 во vkontakte - 140 в twitter 
# Конфигурация выполнена.

# Дальше можно не читать :)

# Объявляем Дуровский UserAPI
class vkuserapi {
    private $curlh = null;
    public $uid = null;
    private $sid = null;

    public function __construct ($login,$password) {
        $this->curlh = curl_init();
        $request = 'http://login.userapi.com/auth?site=2&login=force&pass='.urlencode($password).'&email='.urlencode($login);
        curl_setopt($this->curlh, CURLOPT_URL,$request);
        curl_setopt($this->curlh, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);
        curl_setopt($this->curlh, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, false);
        curl_setopt($this->curlh, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($this->curlh, CURLOPT_POST, false); 
        curl_setopt($this->curlh, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
        $auth_result = curl_exec($this->curlh);
        if (preg_match("/remixmid=(\d+)/", $auth_result, $matches)) $this->uid = $matches[1];
        if (preg_match("/.*;sid=(\w*)/", $auth_result, $matches)) $this->sid = $matches[1];
    }

    public function call ($func,$params) {
        curl_setopt($this->curlh, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
        $request = 'http://userapi.com/data?act='.$func.'&'.http_build_query ($params).'&sid='.$this->sid;
        curl_setopt($this->curlh, CURLOPT_URL,$request);
        $result = curl_exec($this->curlh);
        return json_decode($result);
    }

    public function __destruct () {
        $request = 'http://login.userapi.com/auth?login=logout&site=2&sid='.$this->sid;
        curl_setopt($this->curlh, CURLOPT_URL,$request);
        curl_exec($this->curlh);
        curl_close ($this->curlh);
    }
}

# Берем статус со своей RSS-ленты на Twitter.com
$rss = simplexml_load_file('http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/'.TWITTER_USERNAME.'.rss');
# Убираем лишнюю информацию
foreach ($rss->channel->item as $status) {
    if (strpos($status->title,'@')) continue; // Фильтр реплаев в Twitter
    $last_status_twitter = str_replace (TWITTER_USERNAME.': ','',$status->title); break;
}

# Читаем последний обновлённый статус из файла vtweet.txt
$f=fopen(dirname(__FILE__).'/vtweet.txt','r');
$last_status_vkontakte = fread($f,512);
fclose($f);

# Если последний статус ещё не опубликован во В Контакте, публикуем и помечаем его как обновлённый
if (($last_status_vkontakte != $last_status_twitter) && ($last_status_twitter != NULL)) {
$vkontakte = new vkuserapi (VKONTAKTE_LOGIN,VKONTAKTE_PASSWORD); // Логинимся
$vkontakte->call ('set_activity',array('ts'=>time(),'text'=>PREPEND_WORD.$last_status_twitter)); // Обновляем статус
unset ($vkontakte); // Выходим из Vkontakte.ru
$f=fopen(dirname(__FILE__).'/vtweet.txt','w');
fwrite($f,$last_status_twitter); // "Помечаем" статус как уже обновлённый
fclose($f);
echo 'Updatetd.';
}
else echo 'No update needed.'; // Если последний уже помечен, выводим внутреннюю ошибку.

# Завершаем работу программы.
?>
```

or_die, этот скрипт будет использоваться как на VPS, так и на обычном хостинге. (пришлось редактировать сообщение, т.к. не могу больше добавлять комментарии)

Comment: Тогда вообще незнаю в чём дело. У меня всё работает как по маслу даже с open_basedir

Comment: or_die, если не сложно, напиши мне: bing-pochta@live.ru Хотелось бы разобраться в чем проблема...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Переписал, вроде должно работать :)

```
<?php
##################
$vk_login = 'mail@mail.ru';
$vk_password = 'vkontakte pass';
$vk_page = 'vk puplic page';
$tw_login = 'tw login';
##################
$cookie_file = 'cookies.txt';
$tweet_file  = 'vtweet.txt';
$mode = 1; // 1 - парсим только последнее сообщение 0 -  все сообщения 
##################
VK_Login($vk_login, $vk_password);
$f=fopen(dirname(__FILE__).'/'.$tweet_file,'r');

$rss = simplexml_load_file('http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/'.$tw_login.'.rss');
# Убираем лишнюю информацию
foreach ($rss->channel->item as $status) {
    if (strpos($status->title,'@')) continue; // Фильтр реплаев в Twitter
    $last_status_twitter = str_replace ($tw_login.': ','',$status->title);
    $last_status_vkontakte = fread($f,512);
    if (($last_status_vkontakte != $last_status_twitter) && ($last_status_twitter != NULL)) {
        VK_Page_Sending($last_status_twitter);
        $f=fopen(dirname(__FILE__).'/'.$tweet_file,'w');
        fwrite($f,$last_status_twitter);
        echo ($mode == 1) ? "Update" : "";
    }
    else
    {
        echo ($mode == 1) ? 'No update needed.' : "";
    }
    if($mode == 1) break;
}

fclose($f);

function VK_Login($vk_login,$vk_password)
{
    global $cookie_file;  
    $ch = curl_init();  
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);  
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://vkontakte.ru/login.php?m=1&email={$vk_login}&pass={$vk_password}");  
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Opera/9.64 (Windows NT 5.1; U; ru) Presto/2.1.1");  
    $headers = array(  
    'Accept: text/html, application/xml;q=0.9, application/xhtml+xml, image/png, image/jpeg, image/gif, image/x-xbitmap, */*;q=0.1',    'Accept-Language: ru-RU,ru;q=0.9,en;q=0.8',  
    'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',  
    'Accept-Charset: iso-8859-1, utf-8, utf-16, *;q=0.1',  
    'Accept-Encoding: deflate',  
    'Cookie2: $Version=1',  
    'Connection: Keep-Alive, TE',  
    'TE: deflate, gzip, chunked, identity, trailers');  
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$headers);  
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);  
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_file);  
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie_file);  
    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);  
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_ENCODING , "gzip");
    curl_exec($ch); 
    curl_close($ch);
}

function VK_Page_Sending($message)
{
    global $vk_page, $cookie_file;
    static $hash, $public_id;
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_file);  
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie_file);  
    if(!isset($hash) && !isset($public_id))
    {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://vkontakte.ru/'.$vk_page);
        $answer = curl_exec($ch);
        preg_match('#"post_hash":"(.*?)"#',$answer,$hash_array);
        preg_match('#"public_id":(\d+)#i',$answer,$public_id_array);
        $hash = $hash_array[1];
        $public_id = $public_id_array[1];
    }

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://vkontakte.ru/al_wall.php');
    $post_send = array(
                        'act' => 'post',
                        'al' => 1,
                        'hash' => $hash,
                        'message' => $message,
                        'to_id' => '-'.$public_id,
                        'type' => 'all'
                        );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($post_send));
    curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
}
?>
```

Comment: Пишет Updatetd, но публикация не происходит, убрал из строки:
<code>curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://vkontakte.ru/public'.$vk_page_id);<code>
public, т.к. у меня страница без этого префикса, я убирал его - ничего не изменилось.
Но инфа из фида записывается в vtweet.txt. В чем проблема?

Comment: Вроде исправил

Comment: or_die, все по-прежнему, вот лог ошибок:
<code>[Sun Jul 17 20:38:26 2011] [error] [client my_ip] PHP Warning:  curl_setopt() [<a href='function.curl-setopt'>function.curl-setopt</a>]: CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION cannot be activated when safe_mode is enabled or an open_basedir is set in /var/www/user/data/www/site.ru/test.php on line 44</code>
Строка 44:
<code>curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);</code>
Как я понимаю, надо отключать safe_mode и open_basedir в php.ini, но ведь open_basedir выключать не рекомендуется в целях безопасности, есть какие-либо другие выходы?

Comment: 1 Выключить open_basedir  
2 Ловить в заголовках Location и вырезать от туда адрес, потом переходить по ним 
3 Воспользоваться классом, например Snoopy

Comment: вот написал функцию: http://zalil.ru/31433124 
* В файле троеточием я обозначил повторяющийся код, изменил я только function Sending($message).
Скрипт начал выдавать 500 ошибку, видимо, что-то сделал не так, но это, скорей всего, из-за того, что я ознакомился с классом snoopy только сегодня.

Comment: http://snippy.ru/snippet/1239-yemuliruem-curlopt_followlocation-php/

Comment: or_die, сервер 500 ошибку выдал опять, потом я начал искать решение ошибок в логах в гугле, изменял-изменял, может даже и все по старому сделал (очень много изменял, уже запутался), в итоге остались такие ошибки, которые я так и не смог решить: http://zalil.ru/31433984 
<p>&nbsp;</p>
А вот текущая версия test1.php: http://zalil.ru/31433994

Comment: Если вечером дома буду, гляну как ошибку исправить.
У тебя VPS/VDS или просто виртуальный хостинг? 
Если VPS или VDS и нету рядом соседей, то можно отключить open_basedir. Т.е. как бы при взломе, все это обходиться всеровно